# OptaPlanner processing time

Tags: optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to solve a problem very similar to the cloud balancing example. I have 4 small rules written in drools and the whole is executed within Spring boot. The model has 1 cloud processes and 50 computers. The optimizing works great. What I am not understanding is the time it takes to finish, namely 7 minutes.

If I increase the data set size to 1200 processes and 70 computers, it takes 10 min.

I understand this is my laptop and it is not the fastest. But for this small data set, I was expecting the result to be available within seconds if not milliseconds. Is it possible to have such fast processing, especially if I want to do realtime solving.

I am sure I am missing something. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

First off, run optaplanner-benchmark. The best score graph will show you quality vs time spend.

Second, look at your score calculation speed (last info log line). That should be above 1000, preferably above 5000. Figure out which constraints are slow using that number.

Third, you can use moveThreadCount to enable mutlithreaded solving.

Fourth, to do millisecond solving, look at real-time solving in the docs, specifically addProblemFactChange().